# Elasticsearch simple term query gives strange scores

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch version: 5.0.2

I populate my index with:

```
{_id: 1, tags: ['plop', 'plip', 'plup']},
{_id: 2, tags: ['plop', 'plup']},
{_id: 3, tags: ['plop']},
{_id: 4, tags: ['plap', 'plep']},
{_id: 5, tags: ['plop', 'plip', 'plup']},
{_id: 6, tags: ['plup', 'plip']},
{_id: 7, tags: ['plop', 'plip']}
```

Then, I would like to retrieve the max relevant rows for tags `plop` and `plip`:

```
query: {
  bool: {
    should: [
      {term: {tags: {value:'plop', _name: 'plop'}}},
      {term: {tags: {value:'plip', _name: 'plip'}}}
    ]
  }
}
```

which is equivalent to (but I used the former one to debug):

```
query: {
  bool: {
    should: [
      {terms: {tags: ['plop', 'plip']}}
    ]
  }
}
```

Then, I find really strange scores:

```
[
  { id: '2', score: 0.88002616, tags: [ 'plop', 'plup' ] },
  { id: '6', score: 0.88002616, tags: [ 'plup', 'plip' ] },
  { id: '5', score: 0.5063205, tags: [ 'plop', 'plip', 'plup' ] },
  { id: '7', score: 0.3610978, tags: [ 'plop', 'plip' ] },
  { id: '1', score: 0.29277915, tags: [ 'plop', 'plip', 'plup' ] },
  { id: '3', score: 0.2876821, tags: [ 'plop' ] }
]
```

Here is the detail of the response:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 6,
    "max_score": 0.88002616,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "myindex",
        "_type": "mytype",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.88002616,
        "_source": {
          "tags": [
            "plop",
            "plup"
          ]
        },
        "matched_queries": [
          "plop"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "myindex",
        "_type": "mytype",
        "_id": "6",
        "_score": 0.88002616,
        "_source": {
          "tags": [
            "plup",
            "plip"
          ]
        },
        "matched_queries": [
          "plip"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "myindex",
        "_type": "mytype",
        "_id": "5",
        "_score": 0.5063205,
        "_source": {
          "tags": [
            "plop",
            "plip",
            "plup"
          ]
        },
        "matched_queries": [
          "plop",
          "plip"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "myindex",
        "_type": "mytype",
        "_id": "7",
        "_score": 0.3610978,
        "_source": {
          "tags": [
            "plop",
            "plip"
          ]
        },
        "matched_queries": [
          "plop",
          "plip"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "myindex",
        "_type": "mytype",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.29277915,
        "_source": {
          "tags": [
            "plop",
            "plip",
            "plup"
          ]
        },
        "matched_queries": [
          "plop",
          "plip"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "myindex",
        "_type": "mytype",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "tags": [
            "plop"
          ]
        },
        "matched_queries": [
          "plop"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So, two questions:

1. Why a row maching only one query (id 2 and 6) have a better score than one matching two (id 1, 5 and 7)?
2. Why two rows having the same tags can have different scores? (id 1 and 5)

Did I miss something?

Comment: tags is not_analyzed  ?

Comment: map tags as not_analyzed and it will work fine

Comment: It does not work. Take a look at my comment on the first answer for more informations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I had is nicely explained in the answer of **jgr**.

The solution I've found is to use `dfs_query_then_fetch` as [search type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-type.html#dfs-query-then-fetch).

Here is the resulting query with the JavaScript client:

```
body: {
  query: {
    bool: {
      should: [
        {terms: {tags: ['plop', 'plip']}}
      ]
    }
  },
  searchType: 'dfs_query_then_fetch'
}
```

> Note that with more data in the index type, this certainly wouldn't be needed because scores would balance naturally between shards.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i figure out your real problem. Elasitcsearch by default use 5 shards to store your index data, and if you have small number it can matter in case computing your _score value. Some theory about shards: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_basic_concepts.html

Why does it matter? Because for better performance each shard make _score computing on his own data. But while computing score value elasticsearch use IDF/TF algorithm which relies on total number of docs and frequency of searching terms (IN SHARD) (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html)

To solve this problem you can create index with one shard like this:

```
{
"settings": {
        "number_of_shards" :   1,
        "number_of_replicas" : 0
    },
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "tags": {
          "type":  "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can verify my theory using ?explain in your search query:

> http://localhost:9200/test1/my_type/_search?explain

Or you can read this example if you need more ;)
Those are my results for your query: ["plop", "plip"]

```
{
  "took": 5,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 6,
    "max_score": 0.9808292,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "my_type",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.9808292,
        "_source": {
          "tags": [
            "plop",
            "plup"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "my_type",
        "_id": "6",
        "_score": 0.9808292,
        "_source": {
          "tags": [
            "plup",
            "plip"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "my_type",
        "_id": "5",
        "_score": 0.5753642,
        "_source": {
          "tags": [
            "plop",
            "plip",
            "plup"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "my_type",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.36464313,
        "_source": {
          "tags": [
            "plop",
            "plip",
            "plup"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "my_type",
        "_id": "7",
        "_score": 0.36464313,
        "_source": {
          "tags": [
            "plop",
            "plip"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "my_type",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "tags": [
            "plop"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Why is document with plop,plip,plup as third? Check explain for this one:

```
   "_shard": "[test][1]",
        "_node": "LjGrgIa7QgiPlEvMxqKOdA",
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "my_type",
        "_id": "5",
        "_score": 0.5753642,
        "_source": {
          "tags": [
            "plop",
            "plip",
            "plup"
          ]
        },
```

This is the only one doc in this shard: test[1] (i verified in other returned docs) !! So IDF value is equal to '1' which is the highest possible value. Score = TF/IDF (so for lower IDF, the score is higher). Check how this 0.5753642 score is computed for this doc:

```
 "value": 0.2876821,
                  "description": "weight(tags:plop...

                      "details": [
                        {
                          "value": 0.2876821,
                          "description": "idf(docFreq=1, docCount=1)",
```

sum with

```
  {
                  "value": 0.2876821,
                  "description": "weight(tags:plip..

                          "value": 0.2876821,
                          "description": "idf(docFreq=1, docCount=1)",
                          "details": []
                        },
```

Comment: It does not work. I think that most of analyzers analyze 'plop' and 'plip' as 'plop' and 'plip' so I'm not so surprised. Moreover, I don't think a wrong analyzer would explain the issue 2. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Gnucki Yes u are right! Now i inserted exactly the same documtens as yours and also got those strange results. I explained this and gave you solution to fix this.

Comment: Thank you very much for you investigation! This is exactly what happens, you're right. However, setting only one shard is a bit hard to solve the problem. I used [searchType](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-type.html#dfs-query-then-fetch) instead